# Prove that $f$ is a contraction.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic in a convex region $D$ and $|f'|\le 1$ throughout $D$. Prove that $f$ is a contraction, that is, show that $|f(b)-f(a)|\le|b-a|$ for all $a,b$ in $D$.

Since $f$ is analytic, it is differentiable in $D$. This seems like we would use the mean-value theorem, namely there exists $c$ such that $f'(c)=(f(b)-f(a))/(b-a)$. Then we take the absolute value of both sides and $|f'|<1$. So $|f(b)-f(a)|<|b-a|$, but I'm not sure if I can use the Mean Value Theorem applies, since we do not know if $f$ is real-valued. Also I haven't used that the region is convex. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If it's a complex-valued function of a complex variable, and $f'$ is its complex derivative rather than some sort of matrix-valued derivative of a real-vector-valued function of a real-vector-valued variable, then the mean value theorem for real-valued functions of a real variable would not be directly applicable.

Comment: For $a,b \in D$ you can consider $f$ as a map on the segment $[a,b] = \{ta + (1-t)b: t \in [0,1]\}$. Now this is basically a differentiable map $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and the vector valued MVT applies.

Comment: ....but could somewhat indirectly applicable as in "PZZ"'s comment.

Comment: To refrain oneself from wrongly applying the MVT to complex valued functions, one can keep in mind the case $f(z)=\mathrm e^{z}$: for $a=0$ and $b=2\mathrm i\pi$, $f(b)-f(a)\ne(b-a)f'(c)$ for **any** complex number $c$, since $f(b)=f(a)$ but $f'(c)=\mathrm e^c\ne0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $[w,z]$ denote the directed line segment from $w$ to $z$.  Note that if $w$ and $z$ are in $D$, then so is $[w,z]$ (exactly the definition of convexity).  If we fix $a\in D$, then for all $z\in D$, $f(z)=f(a)+\int\limits_{[a,z]}f'(w)dw$ (an application of a version of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for analytic functions integrated over curves).  Subtract $f(a)$, apply absolute values, and bound the integral using the hypothesis on the derivative to finish (I have seen physicists call the relevant bound on the integral "Darboux's inequality" (q.v.)).

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{aligned}
     |f(b)-f(a)| = &|\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}f((1-t)a+bt)\,dt| \leq \\
                   &\int_0^1 |\frac{d}{dt}f((1-t)a+bt)|\,dt = \\
                   &\int_0^1 |f'((1-t)a+bt)(b-a)||\,dt \leq \\
                   &\int_0^1|f'((1-t)a+bt)|b-a|\,dt \leq |b-a|.\\
\end{aligned}$$